# Understanding the number of aggregations of BLS signatures

Tags: signature, consensus, validators

I know there are about 1 million validators in the consensus layer. As far as I understand, BLS signatures from some of these are aggregated in each block. But how does this happen in practice? In the picture below, I understood that the aggregators are aggregating signatures from attestations with the gossip protocol. I wonder about the following:

1-) Signatures coming to aggregators are aggregated from a committee. In other words, the signatures of everyone in the committee reach the aggregator as a single aggregated signature. Is it true?

2-) How many signatures are aggregated in total? How many of the 1 million validators have contribution to the last BLS signature?

[image: attestation_schematic]